# Adjusting STATA id and t columns with a user-friendly matlab function

Tags: matlab

Here is a piece of matlab code that seems very peculiar. For some time flow reasons, sorting id and t columns the data thoroughly makes stata working almost faster than Excel usage.

```
function output = stataenterance(N,T)
%   generating id and t columns in stata 
%   helping stata data entrance
    time=(1:T)';
    t=repmat(time,N,1);
    for i = 1:N 
        x=i*ones(T,1);
    end
    idc=cell(N,1);
    for i=1:N
        for j=1:N
            idc{j} = repmat(j,T,1);   
        end
    end
    id=cell2mat(idc);
    output=[id t];
```

Is there any alternative way do you know faster than this code? Thanks a lot :D

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question, can you edit to give more detail?

Comment: sure, I was always forced to organize my data for stata entranrence in panel data analaysis. I must fix two columuns which seems very long lots of time. One of them is individual columun and second of them is time

Comment: What's more, the first loop is fully useless, you redefine `x` N times, why not directly give it the value `x = N*ones(T,1)`

Comment: It is true friends, the first loop is for finding a paralell way. x is useless